# iOS app Photo on all Apple devices

Tags: ios, ios8, avfoundation

I'm creating a photo application on iOS.
The application takes pictures in full resolution (all device screen). The application allows you to add content to the photos as stickers and other. The problem is that the difference in size of an iPhone 6/6 + and 4s, is too large. If the user manipulates the bottom of the photo on an iphone 6 this will not be visible on an iPhone 4s and inconspicuous on an iphone 5 / 5s.
How it happens Snapchat you to manage all screen sizes?
Are there some tricks to settle this problem?

Comment: Actually the camera on each device takes pictures in much higher resolution than what's visible on the screen. So it have nothing to do with the individual devices, but rather, as proved in the answers, the calculation of the aspect ratio, allowing you to scale the images up/down.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the idea of "Scale to Fit" of Apple. That mean you will scale the image as large as possible but no piece of image is out of screen. In your case, image take by iphone 6/6+ will have 2 black area in left and right side when display in iphone 4.

to scale it, you can use this trick

```
float scaleWidth = view.frame.size.width / image.size.width;
float scaleHeight = view.frame.size.height / image.size.height;

float scale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width * scale, image.size.height * scale);
```

Comment: The term here isn't `scale`, but rather `(aspect) ratio`. (It's easier to look up when knowing the right terms)

Comment: "Scale to Fit" is a term of Apple. and also, aspect ratio = width : height. and in my code, there's no place for aspect ratio. I keep the aspect ration of image by multiple height & width of image with a same number.

Comment: That sounds great. I will try it.

Comment: The camera takes by default 4:3 resolution right. So how can i display 4:3 fit on all device ?

Comment: yes, you can. but sometime, the resolution is 3:4 (when you take photo landscape) or 1:1 (for square image, natively supported by ios 8). that's why i purpose the solution without hardcoded ratio.